# How to use a release branch on remote with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I am a GIT user who is trying to deploy a Mercurial branching system. The aproach will be simple:

- Master branch with the current status of production.
- Release branches with the next set of changes in master.
- Feature branches.

So far I got the basics to commit changes and update them, but I still have some doubts about remote branching that you might can help me:

- How to create a remote "release-x-x" branch?
- How to switch to a remote "release-x-x" branch?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You'll have to forget 99% of Git's perversions (and own Git's terminology) in Mercurial world
- Mercurial has not concepts of "remote branches" and, respectively, local "tracking branches"
- **Default** Mercurial **behavior** on push is "push all existing branches in repo" (while `hg push -b` also exist), contrary to Git policy

In order to "create" remote branch you can push (to pre-existing remote repository) from local repository only needed branch. But this remote repository will not be linked in any way with this single branch in future - you can continue to push only this branch or add on push any others from full set

"Switch" to remote branch isn't possible AFAICS

Maybe you'll describe you business-task in plain English (without using any Git background and terms and habits) so that we can construct Mercurial (or VCS-agnostic way) solution: just as dirty hint - it's possible (I suppose) to  build alias(es), which will push only one (current) branch to linked remote repository without additional user's intervention